# How to construct an empty DeviceInformationCollection?

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I'm implementing an interface that returns a [`DeviceInformationCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformationcollection). The implementation can time out (or fail), in which case I would like to return an empty collection. This is to allow clients of the interface to always iterate over the returned collection, regardless of whether it succeeded or not, e.g.

```cpp
auto&& devices{ co_await MyType::GetDevicesAsync() };
for (auto&& device : devices)
{
    // Do crazy stuff with 'device'
}
```

However, I cannot figure out, how to construct an empty `DeviceInformationCollection`. The following code 'works', but causes undefined behavior when clients use the code above:

```cpp
IAsyncOperation<DeviceInformationCollection> MyType::GetDevicesAsync()
{
    // Doing Guru Meditation
    // ...
    co_return { nullptr };
}
```

My current workaround is to return an `IVector<DeviceInformation>` instead, and copy the items of the internal `DeviceInformationCollection` into the vector on success. That's both tedious as well as inefficient. I'd much rather just return the `DeviceInformationCollection` as-is, and construct an empty collection on failure.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Not so sure if I understand correctly. Did the exception happen on this code **"for (auto&& device : devices){   }"**? 
If you add this line **"if (devices == nullptr) { }"** before the "for loop", will the exception happen? 
And it seems you are right that **DeviceInformationCollection** can't be constructed manually, we can only return a **nullptr**.

Comment: @fay: That's correct, executing the range-based for loop raises an access violation due to dereferencing a null pointer. Client code could add a check (`if (devices) {...}`), but I'd much rather not have my interface burden clients with an additional error mode.

Comment: I made the following attempt to convert an empty **"IVector"** to **"DeviceInformationCollection"** in order to construct an empty **"DeviceInformationCollection"**:`IVector<DeviceInformation> myVector{ winrt::single_threaded_vector<DeviceInformation>() }; DeviceInformationCollection myColl = myVector.as<DeviceInformationCollection>();`

Comment: @fay: Interesting. I stripped this down to `co_return single_threaded_vector<DeviceInformation>().as<DeviceInformationCollection>();`, and it appears to work as intended. Although the underlying `std::vector` does get destroyed on the way out of the method, and I'm not sure about the effects of that. Actually, I'm not sure about the ownership semantics of the `IVectorView` interface altogether, in other words: Does this work because the code is correct, or does this not fail, because the (dangling) pointers into the `std::vector` never get dereferenced?

Comment: My test was based on the code.The **"as"** function returns the requested interface and  **"DeviceInformationCollection"** is inherited from "IVectorView",so I tried to use **"as"** function to convert **"IVector"** to **"DeviceInformationCollection"**.But actually I'm not very clear about the underlying principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Officially, this is not supported as the DeviceInformationCollection class does not provide a way to create an empty instance of itself. Unless you can find some function in the Windows.Devices.Enumeration API that does this for you you're out of luck.

Unofficially, we can observe that the default interface for the DeviceInformationCollection class is IVectorView. This means that this interface represents the class on the ABI. So you can play tricks with this knowledge but in general, this is very dangerous because APIs that accept a DeviceInformationCollection as input may assume that its implementation is exclusive and thus rely on some internal layout that you may not be aware of. Better to return IVectorView every time in a polymorphic and safe manner. Something like this:

```cpp
using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;
using namespace Windows::Devices::Enumeration;

IAsyncOperation<IVectorView<DeviceInformation>> Async()
{
    DeviceInformationCollection devices = co_await // ... some async call

    if (devices)
    {
        co_return devices;
    }

    // Returns empty IVectorView...
    co_return single_threaded_observable_vector<DeviceInformation>().GetView();
}

int main()
{
    for (auto&& device : Async().get())
    {
        printf("%ls\n", device.Name().c_str());
    }
}
```

Comment: That's helpful, thank you. There's just one thing I still don't understand: `IVectorView` is a non-owning view. By the time `Async()` returns, the underlying container has gone out of scope. Is this still safe? I understand, that client code isn't going to do any more than access its `Size` property and determine, that there's nothing more to do. But there still are dangling pointers/iterators, and I don't know whether this alone comprises undefined behavior as far as C++ goes, which could cause an aggressive optimizer (like Clang's) to do all sorts of surprising things.

Comment: The statement "IVectorView is a non-owning view." is false. It is only a view in the sense that it does not provide methods for modifying the vector. It is still required to maintain any references to the vector that it represents.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I had the semantics confused with `winrt::array_view`'s.